# Split declaration and defintion of c++ enum class

Tags: class, c++11, enums

I'd like to use a enum class in the following way

```
// Foo.h
enum class Foo : uint8_t;
```

with

```
// Foo.cpp
enum class Foo : uint8_t {
  FOO = 0,
};

// Bar.cpp
enum class Foo : uint8_t {
  FOO = 1,
};
```

and

```
// MainLinkedWithFoo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
int main () {
  (void)Foo::FOO;
  return 0;
}

// MainLinkedWithBar.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
int main () {
  (void)Foo::FOO;
  return 0;
}
```

But I get following error

> incomplete type 'Foo' named in nested name specifier

Does somebody know how to solve this "problem"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can forward-declare scoped enums, but at the time you refer to the actual enumeration identifiers (e.g. `Foo::FOO`), the complete enum definition must be available to the compiler.

Most often, scoped enums are neither an implementation details passed through interfaces nor a bottleneck for your compile times. Hence, the straightforward fix is to put the definition into the header file.

```
// Foo.h
enum class Foo : uint8_t {
  FOO = 0,
  BAR = 1
};
```

But as you explicitly asked for separate declaration and definition, you might want this:

```
// FooFwd.h
enum class Foo : uint8_t;
```

and the definition in `Foo.h` as above. Then, whenever you want to use an enumeration instance without referring its actual enumerators, you can just `#include "FooFwd.h"`, and if you need access to e.g. `Foo::FOO`, go with `#include "Foo.h"`.

Comment: I don't want to assign any value inside Foo.h or FooFwd.h. The values shall only be used/assigned in an .cpp file.

Comment: If you define the enumeration in some translation unit, you can only refer to its enuemrators inside of that translation unit. The enum would be pretty useless. Also, providing multiple definitions as the edit of your question now shows is a violation of the one definition rule. You should only define it once.

Comment: Don't understand the one definition rule problem
"g++ MainLinkedWithFoo.cpp Foo.cpp"
or "g++ MainLinkedWithBar.cpp Bar.cpp"

Comment: Ok I get it, you don't link both definitions together into one executable. Then no ODR violation, but still you can't refer to `Foo::FOO` without the definition at hand.